# Sitecore User Group London - January 2017

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, community-event

It's with great pleasure that we'd like to announce the first Sitecore User Group of 2017 in London. The evening is being hosted for the first time at Valtech, who will be laying on food, drink, good company and of course excellent speakers on all things Sitecore.

The lineup and format of the evening is still being worked on, but could take the form of Lightning talks! Please get in touch if you are interested in presenting!

- Date/Time (local): **Thursday, 12th January 2017 at 6:30pm**
- Date/Time (UTC): **Thursday, 12th January 2017 at 6:30pm**
- Location: **Valtech, 46 Colebrooke Row, London N1 8AF**
- Event Details: [Meetup Details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/sug-uk/events/235363512/)
- Contact: [@m_dresser](https://twitter.com/m_dresser) (twitter) / @matthew.dresser (slack)

**UPDATE** The presentations have now been confirmed as:

- **Sitecore on Azure PaaS** - *Johannes Zilstra* (Sitecore)
- **Scaling MongoDB for Sitecore solutions** - *Nick Hills* (Sitecore MVP, True Clarity)
- **Rendering Chrome for Sitecore Components** - *Kamruz Jaman* (Sitecore MVP)
- **Importing Data Into Sitecore** - *Matthew Dresser* (Valtech)
- **EXM 3.4 and beyond** - *Steve McGill* (Sitecore)

Comment: I have added this event to the board. Community bulletin promotion will begin 10 days before the event.

Comment: Once you have more information about the presentation sessions and the speakers, please edit your post to include that information.